# Is there a good equivalent to eqnarray that allows custom alignment of each tab stop?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

I want to align some elements of equations, and in the process be a good TeX / MathJax user and [avoid `eqnarray`](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf), but can't figure out how to align equations the way I want.

```
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& \frac{1}{2}b+c+d = e        \\
f &=& \frac{2}{3}g+h   = i+j+k
\end{eqnarray}$$
```

produces this (I'm using MathJax, so please excuse me if the TeX implementations do something different):

[image]

whereas if I do this

```
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
a &=& \frac{1}{2}b+c+d &= e        \\
f &=& \frac{2}{3}g+h   &= i+j+k
\end{array}$$
```

I get

[image]

which has the alignment the way I want (equals signs aligned) but the spacing is ugly, and the fractions are inline-style rather than display style.

Is there an environment that I can use which would "do the right thing" and keep me in display style while keeping the spacing the way it looks in `eqnarray`, and allow me to specify the type of alignment at each tab stop?

Comment: You want `alignat`, see the manual of `amsmath`

Comment: interesting... just looked at it, it seems like that works for this case where I have equations, but what if I want to customize the alignment some other way like `rrlrc`?

Comment: There's `IEEEeqnarray` from the package `IEEEtools`

Comment: if you put `eqnarray` inside `$$` you will get an error from latex, I seem to remember mathjax allows it for compatibility with its earliest versions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
a &= \frac{1}{2}b+c+d &&= e        \\
f &= \frac{2}{3}g+h   &&= i+j+k
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Why a double `&`? Because `alignat` builds pairs of `rl` columns (two, in this case), so we want to jump over the second `r` column.

[image]

Comment: close enough, it's not a general answer but it worked for me. Thanks for the explanation.